# array to assoc

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => [RESPONSE]

    [1] => DESCRIPTION=Attribute value is not unique

    [2] => CODE=540

    [3] => 

    [4] => QUEUETIME=0.003

    [5] => RUNTIME=0.003

    [6] => 

    [7] => EOF

)
Array
```

And I want to make it into

```
array( [DESCRIPTION] => Attribute value is not unique, [CODE] => 540 ...);
```

How can I do this? I can't use the explode because it is an array?

Comment: What is `[RESPONSE]` and the other values? The way you desribed your array, they ... well, are not valid PHP ^^

Comment: This already looks really hashy, Might be worthwhile to back up a step or two and explain what you're working with and your goal...

Comment: Is this an .ini file you're attempting to parse? (If so, see @Mark Baker's answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that PHP has one, but heres a simple function to do it (tested):

```
$array2 = array();
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    $values = explode("=", $value);
    if(count($values) > 1)
    {
        $newValue = "";
        for($i = 1; $i < count($values); $i++)
        {
            $newValue .= $values[$i];
        }

        $array2[$values[0]] = $newValue;
    }
    else
    {
        $array2[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't take into account that the string may contain more than one "equal sign"...

Comment: Fixed, even though based on the content given strings didn't include more than one.

Comment: Please don't post untested code. Test it and post it, or don't post it.

Comment: Hey, guess what, once I got my random java syntax out of there, it works! I wrote it on the fly, more for the theory, rather than they "here's how to do it exactly." The theory worked just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If this is what I think it is, why not use PHP's built-in [parse_ini_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function to read the file into an associative array automatically? or [parse_ini_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) if it's not coming from a file source?

Comment: Because this may not be what you think??

Comment: It may not be what I think, @NemoStein, but it certainly looks like part of a .ini file... I'd be remiss if I didn't make the suggestion though, and offered a more kludgy approach to parsing the array manually when it could have been parsed easily by a single function call

Answer (score 0):

Whilst a bit of a brute force approach, the following should work:

```
<?php
    $testArray = array('[RESPONSE]', 'DESCRIPTION=Attribute value is not unique', 'CODE=540', 'QUEUETIME=0.003', 'RUNTIME=0.003');
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($testArray as $element) {
        if(strpos($element, '=') !== false) {
            list($key, $value) = explode('=', $element, 2);
            $newArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    print_r($newArray);
?>
```